# java error 404 path api after i have convert batch jar to war

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a project that was thought of as a batch but as I was using the evolutions, it was transformed into a rest api with an automaton, the project works well but I had to convert it from jar to war and there I have a error 404 when I call my services.

so i add packaging war and add `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` with scope privided and add extends `SpringBootServletInitializer` to main class

but when i call my application i have 404
whith
http://localhost:8088/warname/api/park

http://localhost:8088/warname/park

http://localhost:8080/warname/api/park

http://localhost:8080/api/park

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.csg</groupId>
    <artifactId>batchMajPark</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>batchMajPark</name>
    <description>Batch Park Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.2.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

properties

```
server.port=8089
```

does need auther things likes index page web.xml, ... ?

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/park")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class parkEndpoint {
...
}
```

so i want a war that works on tomcat 10

```
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/ java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name: Apache Tomcat/10.0.23
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Compil├® Server: Jul 14 2022 08:16:11 UTC
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version: 10.0.23.0
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name: Windows 10
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version: 10.0
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture: amd64
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home: C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\Jdk-11.0.15
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version: 16.0.1+9-24
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM provider: Oracle Corporation
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE: C:\Users\apache-tomcat-10.0.23
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME: C:\Users\apache-tomcat-10.0.23
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\apache-tomcat-10.0.23\conf\logging. properties
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\apache-tomcat-10.0.23
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\apache-tomcat-10.0.23
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\apache-tomcat-10.0.23\temp
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loading Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.35] using APR version [1.7.0]
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR Features: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true], UDS [true]
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1q 5 Jul 2022]
INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Protocol handler initialization ["http-nio-8080"]
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization took [703] milliseconds
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlets Engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.0.23]
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of the archive [C:\Users\apache-tomcat-10.0.23\webapps\batch-maj-park.war] of the Web application
INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR file was ├®scanned├® for TLDs but it did not contain any, log debug mode can ├ be enabled to get a full list of unsuccessfully scanned JARs; ├®avoiding unnecessary parsing of JARs can significantly improve
```

Comment: Please add more information: Do you create a war and deploy it to a server? Or do you want an embedded tomcat server? Do you have a rest controller for /api/park? Do you have start up logs for the spring application? Please create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: of course i have an api, and yes  have packaging war file

Comment: As far as i remember, tomcat 10 uses the new Jakarta EE API, while Spring Boot 2.x uses the "old" JEE API. So you should use Tomcat 9.x for Spring Applications. In your tomcat logs I don't see any deployment of an applicaton.

Comment: it's work with tomcat 9